# How can I test an express server without sending requests?

Tags: node.js, express, testing

I'm an educator helping to teach a course that covers the basics of writing HTTP servers using Express. Currently, our students test their servers by starting them up, then running Jest separately, using `fetch` to send requests to their server.

Usually, the small performance overhead of sending these requests would not be a problem, but as we have hundreds of students, each with a CI pipeline that takes about 2 minutes to run, it places a lot of strain on our systems, especially when it is close to deadlines, where our runners can get up to 24 hours behind.

As such, I am looking for a way to speed up tests by mocking the requests. Essentially, I want students to be able to write code that looks similar to a `fetch` request, but rather than being sent through `localhost`, it is sent directly into the Express server, which is part of the same process, thereby increasing performance significantly.

In my investigation so far, I've only come across `supertest`, but it appears to fire up the server in the background, meaning that it isn't any faster than sending the requests manually - essentially it just abstracts the running the server part rather than eliminating it.

It is possible to do this kind of testing in Flask, and in numerous other frameworks.

How can I accomplish this in Express in a way that is approachable and reliable?

To be clear, I do not want to migrate an entire university course to GitHub. That shouldn't be the answer to this question. It doesn't even come remotely close to being an answer. Please can I get answers (or at least a "sorry, what you're asking for doesn't exist"), rather than responses that don't address the question?

Comment: Why aren't the students just running the servers on their own computers?

Comment: We also teach CI, so we expect them to create reliable CI scripts and use those results to validate their work before merging it to main.

Comment: Not to mention, many students are using our own lab environment, so even if they did run it from their account where they do their work it would still be using resources

Comment: I know with [GitHub for Education](https://education.github.com/pack) you can get DigitialOcean credits. You can then boot up a Ubuntu VM and install your CI/CD runner of choice and each student can do this as long as they can verify that they are actively enrolled in an accredited university.

Comment: Did you even measure that localhost is the problem? Because honestly, I doubt it.

Comment: @freakish between iteration 1 and 2 of the project, we get students to convert their functions into a web server. Before the conversion, tests take 2-10 seconds to run depending on the group, and afterwards they take 1-2 minutes. If this isn't due to the overhead of sending a request from one process then receiving it in another process then what could it be? I don't think the process of JSONifying some objects is gonna result in tests running an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @AlexLowe that's great, but would require a significant rewrite of our course - we specifically use GitLab, and have a huge number of scripts that use the GitLab API to perform operations on students' code (releasing assignments, collecting submissions, returning grades, etc). Rewriting that code is neither feasible nor relevant to the question.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge there's not enough details to answer that. (De)serialization might be a bottleneck when each request is cpu bound. But then getting rid of it is pushing things too far - what if the code does something funky with the serialized data? Everything should be tested IMO. Adding more horsepower would definitely be the best solution here. Either way measure here.

Comment: @freakish serialising and deserialising <200 bytes of JSON should not result in the runtime for tests increasing by 10x. In fact, I was able to serialise and deserialise an object roughly the size of the largest request body they will send a million times in just 4 seconds. I know for a fact that none of our students are doing anything funky with the serialised data. I read their code myself. I also doubt that Express is doing funky things with data under the hood - it is one of the most widely-used web frameworks, so if it was needlessly inefficient I think people would have noticed by now.

Comment: @freakish not to mention that extra horsepower isn't within the budget unless we plan on massively reducing our teaching quality by hiring less tutors. Essentially, I wouldn't be asking this question if I hadn't already made sure it was the most-likely path to improvement. I've been investigating various ways to speed things up on-and-off for about a month at this point, so I'm pretty sure I've explored most of the avenues.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge you make so many assumptions about code, about students, about frameworks, but did you actually measure any of that? A particularly funny assumption is that frameworks don't do needlessly inefficient stuff. For example Python json encoder is known too be very slow, so slow that in fact in became a bottleneck in one of our production servers. I've seen hundreds popular and horribly inefficient frameworks. Measure. Don't assume things.

Comment: As I have already said, I have spent a month exploring the problem and investigating possible solutions. I literally did measure - it's not an assumption. I literally encoded and decoded an object that was roughly the size of the body of a request to the most complex route we specify they create a million times. I have also tirelessly read tens of thousands of lines of student code in my time teaching this course. Testing the servers is consistently slow for all students, regardless of their programming ability.

Comment: Either way, @freakish, I'm sure you can understand that encoding a web request and sending it through the kernel then into a separate process where it is decoded and processed is significantly slower than passing around some objects in the memory of one process. That seems like pretty basic knowledge to me.

Comment: I don't understand why they would be sending in one process and receiving in another? Why aren't they starting and cleaning up the server in the test suite itself? If you want to completely remove the network stack you can use a named pipe instead of localhost, but I'm not sure it's going to cut your overhead very much.

Comment: @leitning As far as I can tell, everything just starts up a server in the background. Even if something like supertest was used to start the server in the background, it'd still be run over localhost. I've had a quick google of how to use named pipes with Express, but couldn't find anything meaningful - are you sure that's a thing that is doable?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. I don't know how fetch in jest works, but it's easy enough with a native http request. Supposing you wanted to set the socket at `/tmp/blah` you'd substitute that for `localhost` in the listen call (`app.listen('/tmp/blah')`) and specify `socketPath` in the request (`http.request({ socketPath: '/tmp/blah', method: 'GET', path: '/api/foo/bar' })`)

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I'm highly skeptical that you've actually measured it, because a single localhost server handling tens of thousands of requests per second is not a big deal. I'm highly skeptical because I've seen many things, but never kernel being the bottleneck. And I have a hunch this is XY problem. But I don't have enough data to be sure.

Comment: Also, yes, processing objects without serialization is faster. But significantly? Not necessarily. Again, such claims require measurements. I would claim that JS runtime is significantly slower than kernel and serialization (which is written in C AFAIK). I wouldn't be surprised if it dominates any kernel interaction. Especially if each route is hit only once, because then you have additional overhead of JIT compilation. No, such claims are simply not valid without data backing them up.

Comment: @freakish I've asked "how can I do this" and your answer is "you don't want to do that". Do I need to write an entire thesis to justify every single aspect of my question in order to be deserving of an answer? I have explained and justified myself time and time again and you have ignored all of the evidence I have supplied. When I say I have considered alternatives elsewhere, you say you don't believe me. When I give evidence of the massive slow-downs you ignore the numbers. I just want an answer to my question. I shouldn't need to spend precious time out of my day trying to justify that.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge what evidence? What numbers? I asked you multiple times for evidence that it is kernel that is a bottleneck. Measuring request times is not that. And everything else is speculation. But hey, if your precious time is so important, then who am I to judge? I just wonder though if this is the methodology you teach.

Comment: @freakish ok just for you, I've programmed a benchmark that compares testing flask using web requests (15 seconds on GitHub actions) and using Flask's built-in testing API (3 seconds). The same test runs in 9 seconds for Express using the fetch API. If I can expect a similar improvement if I use a similar technique with Express as I did in Flask, I could reduce that value to about 2 seconds. Even if the improvement isn't quite as drastic, it'll still be an improvement. Here's a link to the workflow run: https://github.com/MiguelGuthridge/best-test-request/actions/runs/5155119210

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I really don't know why you are testing a completely different framework and even language. How is that supposed to get you closer to answering the question? Plus, as I said earlier such tests do not really indicate where the bottleneck is. I don't know why you can't just profile your students code. I think I'm done though, I'm tired of this, good luck.

Comment: @freakish I am testing a completely different language and framework because that language and framework allows me to do what I want to accomplish in express. I am therefore able to determine if there is a meaningful difference to performance when injecting fake requests compared to sending real requests, and in Flask there is a 5x performance improvement. Are you incapable of understanding how that kind of speed-up might be helpful for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you can use a normal unix socket instead of localhost to remove the network stack. But you could also just call the `app.handle` function natively and create your own request and response instances.

*Edit: Note I don't know that what's below is an actual working sample, but it's a jumping off point. You might have to fill in more properties on the instances to make sure express gets everything it's looking for.*

```js
const http = require('http');
let req = Object.assign(
  new http.IncomingMessage(),
  { method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/foobar',
    headers: { host: 'localhost' } }
);
let res = new http.OutgoingMessage();

app.handle(req,res);
```

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_outgoingmessage